# Drag & Drop in Firefox - Label with fixed width only allows dragging when grabbing where there is text

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

** UPDATE **
This appears to only be an issue in Firefox. Works in Chrome and IE.

---

I have a `label` with a fixed width and set to `inline-block` so that it obeys the `width` property. I am trying to drag the label, but it will only grab where there is text. Trying to drag on the empty part of the label will not work.

[This is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/0cwqo7k7/) which shows the problem. Any ideas how to allow the whole label to drag? Just JS and CSS, no jQuery please.

HTML

```
<label id="dragSource" draggable = "true">Won't drag if grab to the right of text:</label>
<div id="dropTarget">Drag Here: </div>
```

Javascript

```
var dragSource = document.getElementById("dragSource");

dragSource.ondragstart = function(event) {
    console.log(this);
    var dataToCopy = event.target.innerText;
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", dataToCopy);
    return true;
};

var dropTarget = document.getElementById("dropTarget");

dropTarget.ondrop = function(event) {
    this.innerText = this.innerText +" "+ event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
};

dropTarget.ondragover = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
};

dropTarget.ondragend = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
};
```

CSS

```
div{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

label {
  display:inline-block;
  width:400px;
  border: solid 1px black
}
```

Comment: @Omarjmh Did you click to the right of the text where it is empty? If so, what browser are you using. I just tested with Chrome and you are right - it worked. But with Firefox it doesn't.

Comment: @Omarjmh It works in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox.

Comment: https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: @Omarjmh I tried `display: -moz-inline-stack;` but it didn't work. In fact, it wouldn't allow dropping at all, although it shows it dragging. Wierd. Although if I stack the two entries as shown in the link, it works - because Firefox now supports inline-block (the article is from 2009 when it didn't).

Comment: Im going to delete my last messages, its just getting a bit busy here, but I'm looking at it, I think we need to  little bit more

Comment: Do you have to use a label here? It seems to be causing all the problems...

Comment: A `span` works fine in terms of dropping, but I will lose the `label`'s functionality: e.g. clicking on it for checkbox and radio  controls which I need.